# Can't access current $stateParams from a global controller that's not attached to one state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a navigation bar with a search field in it. Searched text goes into a query param in my main content route. I would like to be able to check the $stateParams.search (my search param) and set the search field model equal to the current param so if for instance a user shares a url link for a search, then that field will be populated and from a UX perspective the user will know they're in a search return. Currently my controller for navigation is bound directly to the body so.

```
<html>
    <body ng-controller="navCtrl">
        <nav><input type="text" ng-model="searchText"></nav>
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I check my $stateParams from my mainCtrl (main content controller) that is accessed from a ui-router state, I get a list of my current state params. Whenever I try to access it from my navCtrl I get an empty object.

How can I access up to date state params from a 'global' controller or how else can I keep my search bar text in sync in this way?

Answer (score 0):

So I did two things to solve this. First I wrapped my stateParam.search to scope variable assignment in a timeout function to allow a cycle for the $stateParams to actually load. Then I additionally started doing the assignment of $stateChangeSuccess to allow help keep everything in sync.